# Why can't I change passwords using the ldifde tool?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, windows

I'm trying to change user passwords using ldifde tool with the following commmand:

`ldifde -i -h -f .\password.ldf -J ./`

Here is one of the entries that are in the password.ldf file:

```
dn: CN=pwtest,OU=Engineering,DC=MyDc,DC=com
changetype: modify
replace: unicodePwd
unicodePwd::Ik51bWJza3VsbDIxIg==
-
```

I've changed the domain and password in this example but I've assured that the password I'm using meets password policy. I did this by resetting one of the user's password to the password I'm trying to update them all to.

I receive the following error:

```
Add error on entry starting on line 2: Unwilling To Perform
The server side error is: 0x1f A device attached to the system is not functioning.
The extended server error is:
0000001F: SvcErr: DSID-031A129B, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0
```

Im logged into the machine as administrator via RDP and I'm using the local powershell. I have updated the passwords yesterday using this method and it worked fine. The only thing that is different now, that I can know of, is the users now have passwords and I'm attempting to change them. Also, this is Windows server 2012 Datacenter.

Comment: It usually means it doesn't meet the pwd policy...I know what you said though...http://support.microsoft.com/kb/263991

Comment: can you check the logs on the dc?

Comment: also can you change the pw via other methods?  are you a DA or have you been delegated perms to the object?

Comment: I have full admin rights to every domain. I've changed the password to the new one using the Active Directory Users and Computers tool, for a single user. I'll check the DC logs now and report back

Comment: whats the password change frequency policy set to?

Comment: I want to make sure I checked in the correct place. This is my first foray into server admin if you haven't noticed yet. I check in Group Policy Management Editor-> Default domain policies - > Computer Configuration -> Policies -> Windows Settings -> Security -> Account -> Password. Max pw age = 0, Min pw age = 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AD requires an SSL connection to change a password.  Try adding -t 636 to your command.

e.g. ldifde -i -h -t 636 -f .\password.ldf -J ./

You may have other missing dependencies such as high encryption packs / etc.

Added from comments:

> It has to do with how you are encoding the password. You are missing an essential step. It's not just text to base64. Use the PwdToBase64.txt from www.rlmueller.net/Base64.htm Rename it to .vbs and it will encode them properly.

Comment: I changed it yesterday using the exact same method, only a different password. The users at that time did not have a password. I get this error when I try to use SSL. Unable to enable SASL layer signing: Unwilling To Perform.

Comment: Try removing the -h from your command.

Comment: Now I'm getting the original error message again.

Comment: Now you're back to the first comment from TheCleaner.  That error message is indicative of a password not meeting complexity requirements.  Try setting the same password through a gui tool to verify.

Comment: I just reset a user's pw with the gui tool. It accepted the new password.

Comment: It has to do with how you are encoding the password.  You are missing an essential step.  It's not just text to base64.  Use the PwdToBase64.txt from www.rlmueller.net/Base64.htm  Rename it to .vbs and it will encode them properly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9326/discussion-between-pablo-and-zerodivide)